# Date conversion doesn't work

Tags: shell, unix, date, sed

The Date on the second line of the file looks like this

> `12-24-11 13:37 (MM-YY-YY MM:SS)`

I want to convert it into

> `Sat Dec 24 13:37:00 CET 2011`

seconds should always be `00`.

I do this using this code

```
date="$(sed -n 2p $file)"
date="$(echo $date | sed 's#^\([0-9\-]\{5\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)#\2-\1#')"
date="$(date -d $date)"
```

But for reason unknown to me this doesn't work... Any ideas?

I always get the error:

> date: the argument '13:37' lacks a leading '+';
>   When using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
>   argument must be a format string beginning with '+'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
date=$(sed -n '2s/\(.*\)-\(..\) /date -d \2-\1\\ /p' file | sh )
```

Or if you are using GNU sed:

```
date=$(sed -n '2s/\(.*\)-\(..\) /date -d \2-\1\\ /ep' file )
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're sending `12-24-11 13:37`, but you should escape the spaces: `12-24-11\ 13:37` or `"12-24-11 13:37"`, to prevent it from interpreting it as two arguments.

Comment: But when I do it manually from the command line then it works with the spaces... $ date -d '11-12-24 13:37'

Comment: Exactly, you're using `'` to escape them.

Comment: And how do I have to modify the code then? date="$(date -d \'$date\') is obviously not a solution at all :D

Comment: Why's that not a solution? I have to admit I've never done shell scripting, but it should work fine. Maybe without the backslashes though

Comment: If I have to believe the internet, this might work: `date="$(date -d $(printf '%q' $date))"`

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work I get the error: date: invalid date `11-12-2013:37'